# Getting Game Score (Sub String) From String C#

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

What is the best way to extract the score from a string variable. For example extract 2-1 from "Match One 2-1 To Red Team".

I was going to add special characters around the score and do something like this

```
string in = "Match One |2-1| To Red Team";
string out = input.Split('|', '|')[1];
```

But that would involve me adding two characters to hundreds of rows on a CSV file.

Could I split on the dash. The extract numbers into an array somehow?

```
scoreString.Split('-');
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I have wrote this and it works, but doesnt seem very clean.

```
var splitScores = values[0].ToLower().Trim().Split('-');

var leftScore  = Regex.Match(splitScores[0], @"\d+").Value;
var rightScore = Regex.Match(splitScores[1], @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: is it always going to br 2-1?

Comment: Is the format "Match [Some Number Word] x-y To [Red or some other color] Team"?

Comment: Its always going to be a string then the score and then some more text after. I cleaned up the example used.

Comment: `string out = in.Split()[2].Split('-')[1];` I am assuming that the score will be the 3rd word in the phrase. You may have to use regex to find a pattern for score in the phrase if it gets a bit involved.

Comment: I have updated the OP with what I have come up with which works, its just not very elegant. An exact example of what the string could be is "Strongholds on Eden 100-95 Supremacy"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var splitScores = values[0].ToLower().Trim().Split('-');

var leftScore  = Regex.Match(splitScores[0], @"\d+").Value;
var rightScore = Regex.Match(splitScores[1], @"\d+").Value;
```

The above code works for me so Im going to mark this as the answer. Thanks to those that helped.

Comment: This is an inelegant solution.  If you have multiple instances of the same pattern, the Matches() method is a better way to go, and is easily extendable, where this is limiting.  See my answer above to view documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
if(splitScores.Length != 2 || !int.TryParse(splitScores[0].Split().Last(), var leftScore) || !int.TryParse(splitScores[1].Split().First(), var rightScore)
    throw new Exception("Invalid input file);
```

The problem is that you need something to identify the score. If you use '-' it can happen that you split at the wrong position, because of a '-' e.g. in a team name. To avoid this you'll have to use a special identifier (as you did with |).

Comment: No team name has any special characters. This is a one time import and I can see all the team names.

Answer (score 1):

By your layout, it seems that all your match results will be of a similar layout as follows:

> Match [count] [int]-[int] To [Color] Team

If this is the case, then a simple regex should be able to identify and pull the information out of the string into the format desired (in your case, an array with the two values, in order).

This link should get you some more information about pulling matches from the string:

[C# Documentation - Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

However, there is a more significant problem with what is going on here.  The data is currently stored in a manner that is mixing presentation with the data, and this is the reason you are fighting with processing a string at all.  It would be better to implement the CSV file as follows:

```
Match_number,Winner,Winner_Score,Loser_score
1,Red,2,1
2,Blue,3,2
3,Red,4,1
etc...
```

The match number could be inferred, but that is a matter for another time.  If the data were stored in this manner, getting access to the data would be a very simple matter.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy code from https://regexone.com/references/csharp modified to suit your purpose.

```
var s = "Match One 2-1 To Red Team";
s = "Strongholds on Eden 100-95 Supremacy";

string pattern = @"(\d+)-(\d+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);

// This will print the number of matches
Console.WriteLine("{0} matches", matches.Count);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    GroupCollection data = match.Groups;
    // This will print the number of captured groups in this match
    Console.WriteLine("{0} groups captured in {1}", data.Count, match.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("score: " + data[1] + ", score2: " + data[2]);

    // Each Group in the collection also has an Index and Length member,
    // which stores where in the input string that the group was found.
    Console.WriteLine("score found at[{0}, {1})", 
        data[1].Index, 
        data[1].Index + data[1].Length);
}
```